# How would you display a docker output on a web page?

Tags: docker, web, networking, ssh, webserver

I have a webserver running on an host, and a docker image running on another one.
I am trying to display the docker image output on a webpage, and I was wondering what would be the best way to:

1. Draw the console on the web page: very likely html/css and javascript, I had a look at xTerm.js which seems to be a good framework to draw and manage consoles on web pages.
2. Send the docker image output from its host to the webserver host, so I can display it on the user session webpage: I thought about using rabbitmq, storing each line/group of lines in a message, and it would expect an answer if the console needs interaction (which would mean publishing a reply message from the webserver and so on..)
   But it sounds overcomplex, and maybe something else easier such as direct SSH connection between the user page and the docker host might work, instead of using a message queue?

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: How does the Web server communicate with the Docker container?

Comment: Hey, that's actually part of the problem. RIght now the docker container and the webserver are on the same host, so I can just read the output easily, but I am moving them on different hosts, so I was also trying to answer to this question.

Comment: Showing Docker/shell execution in a web browser is exactly what projects like Jenkins, Travisci, github actions, etc all do... Have you tried looking how they do it? Have you tried using websockets?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, I guessed so. I am not entirely sure how could I look at the way github does it tho..? Websockets might me a good idea probably to just send the docker output to my webserver and use html to render it to an html/js terminal.

Comment: You've not mentioned what language your web server is using, but here's a nodejs library solution https://github.com/mthenw/frontail

Comment: Also this one https://github.com/thlorenz/hyperwatch